# Why ng-repeat returns only one value of a list twice?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

```
  <div class="row" ng-repeat="product in products">
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3">
                    <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text"  name="warehouseName"
                                   ng-model="warehouseName"
                                   ng-readonly="true"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
     ....

    </div>                           

   $scope.getAllProductsByWarehouseId = function() {
      
        productService.getAllProductsByWarehouseId($scope.product.id).$promise
            .then(function (response) {
                $scope.products = response;
                 console.log("response", $scope.products[0]);
                 console.log("response", $scope.products[1]);

                for(let i=0; i<=$scope.products.length; i++) {
                    $scope.products = response;
                    console.log("response", $scope.products[i]);//However I have a list, this return one value
                    this.products.push(response);
                }}).catch(function(e) {
                    console.log('Error: ', e);
                    throw e;
                }).finally(function() {
                    console.log('This finally block');
                });

                }
```

Here is a part of my project. When the object product is a list with 3 object.With console log
console.log("response", $scope.products[0]);
console.log("response", $scope.products[1]);
I can see the objects..correctly!!!
But in web broswer i get twice the same object..any ideas to correct it?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I completely understand your problem, but you are assigning the api response to $scope.products twice.

```
             $scope.products = response; //here you assign it after the promise
             console.log("response", $scope.products[0]);
             console.log("response", $scope.products[1]);

            for(let i=0; i<=$scope.products.length; i++) {
                $scope.products = response; // and again here.
                console.log("response", $scope.products[i]);//However I have a list, this return one value
                this.products.push(response); // not sure what this does
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have several issues in your code, the major issue is you assign the response to $scope.products, which looks unnecessary. You should initial the $scope.products with an array, and always push the items into it, rather than override the whole list.

```
$scope.getAllProductsByWarehouseId = function() {
    $scope.products = []
    productService.getAllProductsByWarehouseId($scope.product.id).$promise
    .then(function (response) {
        for(let i=0; i<=$scope.products.length; i++) {
            // $scope.products = response;
            console.log("response", $scope.products[i]);//However I have a list, this return one value
            this.products.push(response);
        }}).catch(function(e) {
            console.log('Error: ', e);
            throw e;
        }).finally(function() {
            console.log('This finally block');
        });

        }
```